# Why if_else function does not work in other data set

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am running an if_else function to create a new outcome vectors from 4 columns of data.

The command is as follows:

```r
payment_amt <- if_else( interest_rate>0,

                        (balance-(balance*amortisation_factor)/(1+(interest_rate/12))^tenor)*((interest_rate/12)/(1-((1+(interest_rate/12))^(-1*tenor)))),

                        0 )
```

This command work well in 1 of my data

[image]

But does not work in other data

[image]

I tried my best to google but could not understand why the command did not work for the second set of data.

Very much appreciate if anyone can help!

Here I attach here my code & the data_work and data_not_work sets for your reference

```r
# Data Work _ test

tenor = data_work[,"ECL_TENOR"]

interest_rate = data_work[,"INTEREST_RATE"]

amortisation_factor = data_work[,"AMORTISATION_FACTOR"]

balance = data_work[,"ECL_BALANCE"]

 

payment_amt <- if_else( interest_rate>0,

                        (balance-(balance*amortisation_factor)/(1+(interest_rate/12))^tenor)*((interest_rate/12)/(1-((1+(interest_rate/12))^(-1*tenor)))),

                        0 )

payment_amt

 

#####################################################

# Data Not work _ Test

tenor = data_not_work[,"ECL_TENOR"]

interest_rate = data_not_work[,"INTEREST_RATE"]

amortisation_factor = data_not_work[,"AMORTISATION_FACTOR"]

balance = data_not_work[,"ECL_BALANCE"]

payment_amt <- if_else( interest_rate>0,

                        (balance-(balance*amortisation_factor)/(1+(interest_rate/12))^tenor)*((interest_rate/12)/(1-((1+(interest_rate/12))^(-1*tenor)))),

                        0 )
```

Here is data

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After posting this question, I found out that during the merging process, the data_not_work set has been hiddenly converted to tible, that why if_else does not work. When I convert it back to data frame, then if_else work.